# wxGrid: how can I unbind EVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGE?

Tags: wxpython

If I bind it in the following way:

wx.grid.EVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGE(self.mygrid, self.on_cell_change)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't bind events like that, that is the old way of doing it.

Use self.Bind(wx.grid.EVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGE, self.on_cell_change). You can then also use self.Unbind(wx.grid.EVT_GRID_CELL_CHANGE) to solve your question

(if self is the grid in this example)

Interesting article: http://wiki.wxpython.org/self.Bind%20vs.%20self.button.Bind